# how to create a dataframe with beta coefficients of regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have the following code, which takes each column of the data frame HF and fit it to the entire dataframe Index. What I am interested then is to produce a dataframe Betas which contains the regression coefficients:

```
col_names = HF.columns
Betas = pd.DataFrame(columns= HF.columns, index = Index.columns)
for name in col_names:
    lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    hf = HF[name]
    model = lm.fit(Index, hf)
    Betas.loc[:][name] = lm.coef_
```

the code runs but what I get is a Betas dataframe with only NaN values. Can you please help understand the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after `.loc` you are slicing the `Betas` dataframe twice, whereas you need to do it only once by using the same set of squared brackets.

This should be your new *for*-cycle

```
for name in col_names:
    lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    hf = HF[name]
    lm.fit(Index, hf)
    Betas.loc[:, name] = lm.coef_
```

As a sidenote, I removed the assignment to `model` as it is not necessary; you can just call the `fit` method on the `lm` object.

Comment: yes, you are right. The model assignment was useless. It all works. Thanks